# Java Do and While validation

Tags: java, validation, loops

I created this simple program where there is a password, for some reason if I input password the program will carry on executing even though I used do and while.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class PassCheck {
  double password;
  int UserInp;

  public void Validation() {
     do{ 
         System.out.println("Please enter the password");
         Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
         int password = in.nextInt();
     } while (password == 1111);

     System.out.println("Please select whether you would like to workout area or perimeter");
     System.out.println("Enter 1 for area and Enter 2 for perimeter");
     Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
     int UserInp = in.nextInt();

     switch (UserInp){
        case 1:
            CircleArea CircleAreaObject = new CircleArea();
                CircleAreaObject.area();
        case 2:
     }
  }
}
```

Comment: If your password is `1111` you should use `while (password != 1111);`, i.e. continue query, if entered password is not `1111`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your int password that you actually assign is only valid inside the brackets of your do { ... } block. In the while, you are referencing the double password which is never 1111.

```
do{ 
    System.out.println("Please enter the password");
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    int password = in.nextInt();  // This "password"...
} while (password == 1111); // is NOT the same variable as this...
```

In the while(password = 1111) you are referencing the double password (as someone already mentioned, why is this double? ). You cannot reference the local int password here, since it's scope is limited to the insides of the brackets above.

Comment: Thank you for your help, but how would I make it the same variable? can you edit it so I can understand please?

Comment: That is simple, you have to declare the `int password` BEFORE the `do {...`. Write, for example, `int password = 0;` and then, inside the do-while block, only assign it with `password = in.nextInt();` And voila, the scope of that local `password` is now the whole method. (And are you sure you want to test for == 1111 and not != ? )

Comment: Oh wow Thank you so much I appreciate it. I thought let me experiment with != and it seemed to work what does '!=' mean. Since it worked with the password validation.

Comment: == means "equals", != the opposite. So you are staying in the do-while loop as long as you enter the password 1111... Normally I would expect you to continue as soon as you enter the correct one...

Answer (score 1):

You have two password variables.  The "while" condition is using the method variable.  You have another variable declared in the scope inside the while condition-- that one is not the one that the "while" condition is using.

So one solution is to pull out your "int password" declaration into a line immediately before the do/while loop.  Then assign it inside the do/while loop scope.  And remove the PassCheck password declaration in the class.

Answer (score 0):

What you have done is to create a new variable `password` of type `int` in the scope of your `do` block, java let you do this because the pacakage-private `password` field declared at the beginning of your class is of type `double` rather than `int` like its's local counterpart. You can correct this problem by making the following changes to your class. Your class also had a lot of style and naming issues which I've cleaned up.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class PassCheck {
  int password;
  int userInp;

  public void validation() {
    do { 
      System.out.println("Please enter the password");
      Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
      password = in.nextInt();
    } while (password != 1111);

    System.out.println("Please select whether you would like to workout area or perimeter");
    System.out.println("Enter 1 for area and Enter 2 for perimeter");
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    int userInp = in.nextInt();

    switch (userInp){
      case 1:
          CircleArea circleAreaObject = new CircleArea();
          circleAreaObject.area();
      case 2:
    }
  }
}
```